# Bulma Modals are cropped inside a VueJS component

Tags: css, vuejs2, bulma

I am using Bulma and VueJS. I am not sure whether the CSS framework here matters; whether this is a VueJS glitch or a Bulma one.

I have created a VueJS component, inside which I plan to use a modal to show an "add item" form, for example.

When I do this, the modal & modal background is constrained to the VueJS component area, and does not fill the whole screen.

Does anyone know why this might occur, and how I can avoid it? I have tried explicitly setting the modal's container to top:0, left:0 and 100% for width and height, but it makes no difference.

Comment: It seems that this is the desired behaviour. Post here and may JT will be merciful. https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/1154